# Parskip seems to reset after tabular environment

Tags: tables, paragraphs, parskip

I am working on a document in which I include some tables. However, when I include the tables, the `\parskip` length seems to reset to 0 afterwards. Why is that and how can I circumvent that?

The code I use with a small example is given in the following. Please note that I included every package I use for the sake of completeness. I do not know where the issue stems from exactly, so better include everything. So some packages are not required to display the following code per se.

The parskip option works fine before the table and is reset after it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
            {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} 
\usepackage{xfakebold}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.25}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=40mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries\boldmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[figure]{aboveskip=10pt} 
\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,font=small}
   
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calc}
\tikzset{
    answer/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=15em, text badly centered, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=4em},
    inout/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=#1, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    line/.style={-{Stealth}}
}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite. 

Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated assistance at. Convinced resolving extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure. Prevent he parlors do waiting be females an message society. 

\smallskip
\captionof{table}{Hypothesis 3} 
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{5}{r}@{}}
  \toprule
  & $Estimation$ & $Standard \ Error$ & $t\text{-}Value$ & $Pr > |t|$  \\
  \midrule
  x. I & 0 & 80 & 80   \\
  x. II & 0 & 1 & 80   \\
  x.  & 0 & 0.39 & 0.02   \\
  x. I & 0 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
  x. II & 0 & 0.00 & 0.13   \\
  x I & (-)** & 0.39 & 0.02   \\
  x II & 0 & 0.08 & 0.00   \\
  x I & 0 & 0.39 & 0.02   \\
  x II & 0 & 0.08 & 0.00   \\
  x & 0 & 0.00 & 0.13  \\
  x & 0 & 0.39 & 0.02   \\
  x & 0 & 0.39 & 0.02  \\
  x & 0 & 0.39 & 0.02  \\
  \bottomrule                             
\end{tabular*}
\caption*{\textit{Notes}: TBD}
\end{scriptsize}
\bigskip

On insensible possession oh particular attachment at excellence in. The books arose but miles happy she. It building contempt or interest children mistress of unlocked no. Offending she contained mrs led listening resembled. Delicate marianne absolute men dashwood landlord and offended. Suppose cottage between and way. Minuter him own clothes but observe country. Agreement far boy otherwise rapturous incommode favourite. 

Cause dried no solid no an small so still widen. Ten weather evident smiling bed against she examine its. Rendered far opinions two yet moderate sex striking. Sufficient motionless compliment by stimulated assistance at. Convinced resolving extensive agreeable in it on as remainder. Cordially say affection met who propriety him. Are man she towards private weather pleased. In more part he lose need so want rank no. At bringing or he sensible pleasure. Prevent he parlors do waiting be females an message society. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of avoiding a proper `table` environment?

Comment: I can not recall exactly. I am not an expert at latex and my document kind of grows on the basis of what I find on the internet. If it is possible to use a table environment that results in the same actual table displayed in the PDF, I am definetly open to use that.

Comment: Hi @shenflow and welcome to TeX.SE! You are stating "I do not know where the issue stems from exactly, so better include everything." and I agree, this is why you are asking this question. Nevertheless you can comment out a package, compile again and check if your issue is still persistent. If this is the case, delete the line from your MWE and go ahead. This shows that you prepared your question well and often times helps you find the issue for yourself.

Comment: The culprit seems to be \captionof->\caption, which admittedly starts and ends with a \par.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify your example to

```
\documentclass[a4paper, bibtotocnumbered,liststotoc,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

[\the\parskip]

\captionof{table}{Hypothesis 3} 
\begin{scriptsize}
\caption*{\textit{Notes}: TBD}
\end{scriptsize}
\bigskip

[\the\parskip]

\end{document}
```

showing the changed value of `\parskip`. Note that you are using `caption` package that documents that `\caption` should not be used at teh top level and the terminal and log file warn:

```
Package caption Warning: \captionsetup{type*=...} or \captionof
(caption)                outside box or environment on input line 10.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

Placing the code inside any environment or even a simple `{...}` group will restore all the local settings after the group.

Comment: Thanks. Putting it into a simple {...} group serves my purpose.